# Is there a way to authenticate a remote session to scrape data and remain authenticated instead of authenticate in each request?

Tags: python, rest, jenkins

I have a python script to scrape data from the jenkins api. The issue is that the script authenticates at each request and that is not performant. I would like to authenticate once and be able to query data as much as I like.

Is that possible?

```
import requests
from basicauth import encode
from pprint import pprint
import json


class JenkinsInfo(object):

    defaultHeader = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, */*',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': ''
    }

    def __init__(self, url, user, password):
        self.jenkins_url = url.rstrip("/")
        self.jenkins_user = user
        self.jenkins_password = password
        self.s = requests.Session()
        self.ssl_verify = ssl_verify
        self.defaultHeader['Authorization'] = encode(user, password)

#### the script below is the one that call previous class ###  

from prometheus_client import start_http_server,Counter
from conf_example import JENKINS_URL, JENKINS_USER, 
JENKINS_PASSWORD
from jenkins_metrics import JenkinsInfo
import time
from sys import exit


def main():
    print("Starting Jenkins Metrics")
    jenkins = JenkinsInfo(JENKINS_URL, JENKINS_USER, JENKINS_PASSWORD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to get a cookie. Make sure you use the same session object throughout the run, and just make your first request a login request. Not sure exactly what Jenkins requires to do a login, but you could probably get some good ideas from the [jenkinsapi](https://github.com/pycontribs/jenkinsapi/blob/master/jenkinsapi/jenkins.py) project or other software doing the same thing. Code copied from them:

```
login_url = 'j_acegi_security_check'
jenkins_url = '{0}/{1}'.format(self.baseurl, login_url)
data = urlencode({'j_username': self.username,
                  'j_password': self.password}).encode("utf-8")
```

Note that they do some things that may not be strictly needed in your use case. Also consider actually using that library, or a similar one, instead of writing your own code from scratch.